# Как отсортировать массив по возрастанию

Tags: c#

Нашел подобный код и он выдает вот такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь мой код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinAPP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }

       public class Data
        {
            public static int Value1 { get; set; }
            public static int Value2 { get; set; }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
                int cols = Data.Value1;
                int row = Data.Value2;
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = cols;
                dataGridView1.RowCount = row;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            int cols = Data.Value1;
            int row = Data.Value2;
            int k;
            int p = 0;
            float[,] array = new float[row, cols];
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    array[i, j] = Convert.ToSingle(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <cols; j++)
            {
                k = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i, j] <= 0)
                    {
                        k = 0; break;

                    }
                }
                if (k != 0) p++;

            }
            label1.Text = "P = " + p.ToString();
            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
            dataGridView2.RowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            if (p <= 0)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < row * cols; ++k)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
                        {
                            if (j != cols - 1)
                            {
                                if (array[i, j + 1] < array[i, j])
                                {
                                    float tmp = array[i, j + 1];
                                    array[i, j + 1] = array[i, j];
                                    array[i, j] = tmp;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if ((array[i+1, 0] < array[i, j]) && (i != row - 1))
                                {
                                    float tmp = array[i + 1, 0];
                                    array[i + 1, 0] = array[i,j];
                                    array[i, j] = tmp;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = array[i, j];


            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
            fr2.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Закрыть программу?", "Подтвердите действие", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Close();
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                dialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Есть код для сортировки по строкам, а мне нужно выполнить сортировку по столбцам

```
            if (p <= 0)
            {
                    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                    {
                       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                        {
                            for (int f = m - 1; f > j; f--)
                                if (array[i, f] > array[i, f - 1])
                                {
                                    float tmp = array[i, f];
                                    array[i, f] = array[i, f - 1];
                                    array[i, f - 1] = tmp;
                                }
                        }
                }
            }
```

Внешний вид программы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что у меня сортируется столбцы или строки?
Нужно: Столбцы матрицы упорядочить по возрастанию значений их элементов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть стандартные методы сортировки, если конечно у вас не задание реализовать их самостоятельно

Comment: У меня в задании просто, если P<0 Выполнить сортировку столбцов по возрастанию. А я не особо понимаю, каким образом, через DataViewGrid кривовато сортируется

Comment: Идите от простого к сложному, сначала реализуйте алгоритм чисто на массивах c выводом на консоль, потом перенесите его на форму

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы хотите достичь следующих целей: 1) уметь набор данных (строк и столбцов) показывать с помощью DataGridView. 2) При нажатии на заголовок столбца - отсортировать по содержимому этого столбца и обновить то, что показывает DataGridView Так?

Comment: А, я, кажется, понял... Вы используете DataGridView просто как средство ввода массива в программу? Ну, типа, написать в нём циферки, а поом нажать кнопку "посчитать" - и программа что то посчитает на основе введенного массива?

Comment: @S.H По заданию ввод непосредственно в dgv, после пробрасывается в массив и выполняется просчет параметра P, в моем задании, это кол-во положительных столбцов, если P < 0, то выполняется сортировка элементов ( столбца) по возрастанию. 
Начальные этап изучения дисциплины.

Comment: Я сейчас не смогу написать готовый пример, но, как я помню, у DGV есть понятие DataSource: это структура данных, "прибитая гвоздями" к визуальному отображению. То есть, если такую струкутуру (возможно, это как раз двумерный массив или "массив массивов") правильно создать и указать в качеcтве DataSource, то произойдет нужная "магия" и, с одной стороны, данные будут показаны на экране, а с другой стороны, при изменении данных на экране они поменяются в связанной с DGV структуре данных. Погуглите про DataSource для DataGridView?

Comment: А ещё в этом задании лучше будет использовать не двумерный массив, а ступенчатый (массив массивов). Т.е. хранить каждый столбец в виде отдельного массива, так как работа идет именно со столбцами. Соответственно работа с индексами будет минимальна. Правда не знаю к с ним будет работать биндинг как предлагает @S.H.

Comment: Я думаю, биндинг  надо делать с простейшим двумерным массивом, а уже по нажатию кнопки преобразовывать его в нужную "внутренюю форму представления", например, в ступенчатый массив. В общем то, бининг просто дпёт возможность работать с вводом - ввыводом через DGV.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос у меня сортируются столбцы или строки
Столбцы матрицы упорядочить по возрастанию значений их элементов.